# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() || Java.Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, исключения, android-asynctask

Я использую AsyncTask в своем андроид-приложении. Но код который там написан почему то вызывает ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Код:

```
    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        String content_str, title_str;
        String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("number");

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            cv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            cv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            content.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Toast.makeText(StoryViewActivity.this, "Number is: "+number.substring(1,number.length()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            title_str = Parser.getStoryByNumber(number.substring(1)).get(0);
            content_str = Parser.getStoryByNumber(number.substring(1)).get(1);
            Toast.makeText(StoryViewActivity.this, title_str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
/*            title.setText(title_str);
            content.setText(content_str);*/

            cv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

логи ошибки:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>                     Process: com.example.len.coolstorybro, PID: 7592
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>                         at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:209)
>                         at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:123)
>                         at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:363)
>                         at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:112)
>                         at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:277)
>                         at com.example.len.coolstorybro.StoryViewActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(StoryViewActivity.java:59)
>                         at com.example.len.coolstorybro.StoryViewActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(StoryViewActivity.java:40)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Более полного текста ошибки нету? Думаю, что проблема в первых двух строках метода кроется, например что будет, если `number` - пустая строка?

Comment: @iksuy Нет, number - точно не пустая строка, В Toast выводится ее содержание

Comment: @iksuy Добавил в пост лог полностью.

Comment: Проблема в `Toast` - если он у Вас для отладки - уберите из `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `Toast` вызывается в `doInBackground` . В `doInBackground` нельзя взаимодествовать с пользовательским интерфейсом. Можете использовать `runOnUiThread` или `onProgressUpdate` для этого, но если вы используете `Toast` только для отладки, то не удобнее ли пользоваться `Log`-ом ?